# How to linearly subdivide a 2D quad mesh?

Tags: mesh, cgal

How can I linearly subdivide a 2D quad mesh ?? It involves simple division of 1 quad face into 4 quad faces. I cannot find such implementation in [cgal](https://www.cgal.org/) , [openMesh](http://openmesh.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  [the barycentric subdivision scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_subdivision)